# What is the purpose of compares in indices in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compare, slice

I encountered the following:

```
r = random.randint(1,6)
C = "o "
s = '-----\n|' + C[r<1] + ' ' + C[r<3] + '|\n|' + C[r<5]
print(s + C[r&1] + s[::-1])
```

When executed in IDLE, this outputs an ASCII die with a random value.

How does it work,and more specifically, what do the compare symbols (`<` and `&`) accomplish inside the indices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someone is code-golfing here, and using hacky tricks to minimise the amount of code used.

- `<` is a regular comparison operator; it returns `True` or `False` based on the two operands. The Python `bool` type is a subclass of `int` and `True` is `1`, `False` is `0` when interpreted as integers. As such `C[r<1]` either picks `C[0]` or `C[1]`.
- `&` is a *bit-wise* operator, not a comparison operator; `& 1` is masking the number to the last bit, effectively testing if a number is odd or even (the last bit is set or not). So if `r` is odd, `C[1]` is used, otherwise `C[0]` is.

Breaking this down:

- `C` is a string with the `o` and space characters
- `C[r<1]` picks either `o` or a space based on wether it is smaller than 1. It never is (`random.randint(1,6)` ensures this), so that is *always* an `o`. This appears to be a bug or oversight in the code.
- `C[r<3]` picks a space for 1 and 2, an `o` otherwise.
- `C[r<5]` picks an `o` for 5 or 6, a space otherwise.
- `C[r&1]` picks an `o` for 2, 4 and 6, a space otherwise.

In all, it prints `r` *plus one* as a die. `r = 1` gives you two pips, while `r = 6` results in *seven* pips, perhaps as a stylised one?

Fixing the code for that requires incrementing all `r` tests and inverting the odd/even test:

```
s = '-----\n|' + C[r<2] + ' ' + C[r<4] + '|\n|' + C[r<6]
print(s + C[1-r&1] + s[::-1])
```

Demo (wrapping the string building in a function):

```
>>> import random
>>> def dice(r, C='o '):
...     s = '-----\n|' + C[r<2] + ' ' + C[r<4] + '|\n|' + C[r<6]
...     print(s + C[1-r&1] + s[::-1])
...
>>> for i in range(1, 7):
...     dice(i)
...
-----
|   |
| o |
|   |
-----
-----
|o  |
|   |
|  o|
-----
-----
|o  |
| o |
|  o|
-----
-----
|o o|
|   |
|o o|
-----
-----
|o o|
| o |
|o o|
-----
-----
|o o|
|o o|
|o o|
-----
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank You